# Force responsive <img> to expand to parent <div>

Tags: html, css, image

for clarity, see codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyaLPb
I want to create an image with an overlay. The overlay should be the same size as the image, however because of the width: 100% and height: auto for both the .imagecontainer and img, they don't have the exact same height. The overlay now has a few pixels more height than the img. You can see the .imagecontainer has more height than the img inside (red background showing at the bottom). I need the imagecontainer and img to be responsive, so setting a fixed height is not really an option. How do I solve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="http://www.kleinewolf.nl/uploads/fancybox/8f5b7a59-32b7-4582-868b- e2ff1f3e41a2/2835832130.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.imagecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.imagecontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display:none;  
}

.imagecontainer:hover .overlay {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: add `line-height: 0;` to `.imagecontainer { ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyaWNE

Added `line-height:0;` to your container div. Images contained by parent divs usually tend to take margins from other elements, and `line-height` and `font-size` are usually a problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking of the red border below the image.

Add to your `.imagecontainer img`: `display: block`. That should solve the problem...

Comment: Yw, consider upvote & accept as answer if it worked :)